# Performing Wilcoxon test with multiple test groups

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I want to run Wilcoxon test to compare 3 test groups (B, C and D) against the control group (A)

The data are organized in the following format:

```
Group   CustomerID  Value
A           23483   61
A           23484   54
A           23485   57
A           23486   59
A           23487   69
A           23488   69
B           23489   57
B           23490   53
B           23491   68
B           23492   59
B           23493   57
C           23494   58
C           23495   70
C           23496   69
C           23497   62
C           23498   53
D           23499   65
D           23500   62
D           23501   60
D           23502   62
D           23503   63
D           23504   68
```

So far I've written the code below

```
#Seperate Control Data
DataControl<- Data%>%
                select(Group,Value)%>%
                filter(Group =="A")

#Filter data
Data%>%
  filter(Group!="A")%>%
  select(Group,Value)%>%
  group_by(Group)
  summarise(p_value = wilcox.test(DataControl$Value,exact =FALSE)$p.value)
```

but I am getting the following errors

```
Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

The desired output shall be

```
Group P-value
B     0.04
C     0.10
D     0.01
```

Comment: Buddy, I think you are missing a pipe operator between group_by and running the Wilcox test.

Comment: omg, sorry and thanks for replying

Comment: But, aside from themissing `%>%`, you are just passing the `DataControl$Value`, giving the same output for each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in pairwise function; I'd start there. Then just tidy it up and pick the pieces you need.

Note that my code (and yours too) doesn't correct for multiple comparisons. You should think about if that's appropriate here.

```
foo <- pairwise.wilcox.test(Data$Value, Data$Group, p.adjust.method="none")
foo

## Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 
## data:  Data$Value and Data$Group 

##   A     B     C    
## B 0.355 -     -    
## C 0.782 0.344 -    
## D 0.470 0.098 0.927
##
## P value adjustment method: none 

library(tidyverse)
broom::tidy(foo) %>% filter(group2=="A")
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   group1 group2 p.value
##   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
## 1 B      A        0.355
## 2 C      A        0.782
## 3 D      A        0.470
```

Comment: As Aaron noted, the pairwise wilcox test doesn't correct for multiple comparisons, it should use a pooled variance. The better test which does that is Dunn's test, and there is these 2 R package for it: `dunn.test` and  `DescTools::DunnTest`

Comment: The `pairwise.wilcox.test` function does correct for multiple comparisons by default, using the Bonferroni-Holm method; I changed that here to match the OP question. However, you are right that the Dunn test is a better way to do that.

Comment: How interesting, I didn't know that. So Aaron, why do you say that the Dunn test is still better?

Comment: From memory, it has more power because it uses the ranks from all the groups instead of redoing the ranks just with the two groups of interest. An overly simple example: 1,2,3 in one group vs 4,5,6 in a second group wouldn't have as much power as 1,2,3 in one group (and then 4-12 in the other groups) vs 13,14,15 in a second group.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to a missing pipe operator, as noted by @OlliePerkins, you also are missing one argument in the call of `wilcox.test`:

```
Data %>%
  filter(Group != "A") %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(p_value = wilcox.test(DataControl$Value, Value, exact = FALSE)$p.value)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Group p_value
#   <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 B       0.355
# 2 C       0.782
# 3 D       0.470
```

where note that `select(Group, Value)` wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issue is the commented one (`%>%` missing) and second the 'x' was only provided and not the 'y' in `wilcox.test`

```
Data %>% 
  filter(Group != "A") %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(p_value = wilcox.test(Value, Data$Value[Data$Group == "A"] )$p.value)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Group p_value
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 B       0.355
#2 C       0.782
#3 D       0.470
```